# How to aggregate an INNER JOIN function to each group after GROUP BY in Hive or Spark

Tags: mysql, apache-spark, hive

I have this table

```
+-------+-------------------+
| id    | email             |
+-------+-------------------+
| 19250 | lazy@gmail.com    |
| 19251 | dummy@uni.co.uk   |
| 19252 | dummy@yahoo.com   |
| 19253 | dummy@outlook.com |
| 19254 | lazy@gmail.com    |
+-------+-------------------+
```

And I want to find different ids having the same email.

```
+-------+-------------------+-------+
| id    | email             | id    |
+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 19250 | lazy@gmail.com    | 19254 |
+-------+-------------------+-------+
```

There are **millions of** records, making INNER JOIN extremely expensive. In fact, the query goes on forever. I am thinking of **grouping all emails by their suffix and to each group I apply INNER JOIN** so that hive compares within group of records instead of global records.

Hope this piece of HQL save some time. Many thanks!

```
CREATE TABLE id_email (id bigint, email string);
INSERT INTO id_email VALUES (19250, "lazy@gmail.com");
INSERT INTO id_email VALUES (19251, "dummy@uni.co.uk");
INSERT INTO id_email VALUES (19252, "dummy@yahoo.com");
INSERT INTO id_email VALUES (19253, "dummy@outlook.com");
INSERT INTO id_email VALUES (19254, "lazy@gmail.com");

CREATE TABLE id_email_suffix
AS
SELECT 
        id
      , email
      , REGEXP_EXTRACT(email, '@([A-Za-z0-9]+\.)+[A-Za-z]{2,14}') AS suffix
  FROM id_email
;
```

which gives

```
+-------+-------------------+--------------+
| id    | email             | suffix       |
+-------+-------------------+--------------+
| 19250 | lazy@gmail.com    | @gmail.com   |
| 19251 | dummy@uni.co.uk   | @uni.co.uk   |
| 19252 | dummy@yahoo.com   | @yahoo.com   |
| 19253 | dummy@outlook.com | @outlook.com |
| 19254 | lazy@gmail.com    | @gmail.com   |
+-------+-------------------+--------------+
```

=============================================

Thank you for your answer, group by and collect_set did part of the job! But still, I need a data frame that looks like

```
+-------+-------------------+-------+
| id    | email             | id    |
+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 19250 | lazy@gmail.com    | 19254 |
+-------+-------------------+-------+
```

And if the size of the collect_set is larger than 2, I need a permutations.
For example, 
if the collect_set = [19250, 19254, 19255], I need

```
+-------+-------------------+-------+
| id    | email             | id    |
+-------+-------------------+-------+
| 19250 | lazy@gmail.com    | 19254 |
| 19250 | lazy@gmail.com    | 19255 |
| 19254 | lazy@gmail.com    | 19255 |
+-------+-------------------+-------+
```

Comment: Is there an index?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, have edited

Comment: Inner join isn't expensive se. But lack of an index is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you  can just groupBy and collect ids and then filter for size of the collection that is not 1

```
scala> df.show(false)
+-----+-----------------+
|id   |email            |
+-----+-----------------+
|19250|lazy@gmail.com   |
|19251|dummy@uni.co.uk  |
|19252|dummy@yahoo.com  |
|19253|dummy@outlook.com|
|19254|lazy@gmail.com   |
+-----+-----------------+


scala> df.groupBy($"email").agg(collect_list("id") as "ids").show(false)
+-----------------+--------------+
|email            |ids           |
+-----------------+--------------+
|dummy@yahoo.com  |[19252]       |
|dummy@outlook.com|[19253]       |
|dummy@uni.co.uk  |[19251]       |
|lazy@gmail.com   |[19250, 19254]|
+-----------------+--------------+

scala> df.groupBy($"email").agg(collect_list("id") as "ids").filter(not(size($"ids") === 1)).show(false)
+--------------+--------------+
|email         |ids           |
+--------------+--------------+
|lazy@gmail.com|[19250, 19254]|
+--------------+--------------+
```

Comment: why `size(collect_list("id"))` and not `count("id")`? it should be `df.groupBy($"email").agg(count("id") as "ids").filter("ids != 1")).show(false)`
`

Comment: looks like the OP wants ids in the output.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The query completes within minute! But how can I explode ids and get id pairs in the output?

Comment: I did not get what you mean by "explode ids and get id pairs". Can you give me an example?

Comment: @C.S.ReddyGadipally Thank you! I have added the example to the question description.

Answer (score 0):

You tagged MySQL, so I'm providing an answer for MySQL

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(email_id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,email VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
,INDEX(email) -- this is the important bit!!
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES 
(1, "lazy@gmail.com"),
(2, "dummy@uni.co.uk"),
(3, "dummy@yahoo.com"),
(4, "dummy@outlook.com"),
(5, "lazy@gmail.com"),
(6, "lazy@gmail.com");

SELECT x.*
     , y.email_id duplicate 
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.email = x.email 
   AND y.email_id > x.email_id;
+----------+----------------+-----------+
| email_id | email          | duplicate |
+----------+----------------+-----------+
|        1 | lazy@gmail.com |         5 |
|        1 | lazy@gmail.com |         6 |
|        5 | lazy@gmail.com |         6 |
+----------+----------------+-----------+
```

This is InnoDB, so (I understand that) the id is implicitly included at the end of the index.

Answer (score 0):

So following @C.S.Reddy Gadipally's idea, I created an UDTF Function that takes a string as argument. 
The string looks like:

```
+--------------+-------------------+
|concat_str                        |
+--------------+-------------------+
|lazy@gmail.com:19250;19254;19255  |
+--------------+-------------------+
```